# How to find a control in a templated control from surrounding NamingContainer

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have created a Usercontrol which has an ITemplate property.

```
    public class MyUserControl
    {
            ...

            [TemplateContainer(typeof(ContextMenuContent))]
            [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
            [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
            [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
            public ITemplate ContextMenuTemplate { get; set; }

            ...
    }
```

The hosting page also contains a **CustomControl** which has a attribute that allows you to set a control ID  of an arbitrary button. My plan is to set the Control ID of a button within the template of **MyUserControl**. The **CustomControl** uses NamingContainer.FindControl() to find the assigned Button, but it seems that FindControl() does not work for controls in ITemplate placeholders. Although I'm able to use Intellisense in CodeBehind for the button and access all its properties, FindControl() is unable to find it.

How can I find the Control in the NamingContainer?

[image]

Comment: Usually you naviate up the control tree: `UserControl.ItemTemplate[i].FindContol("ButtonID"):` Or try it step by step first, like finding `UserControl`. If that works find the `Itemplate` etc

Comment: Ok, but it should be something generic. I expected the FindControl() method to find the same controls as the intellisense mechanism.

Comment: No it does not work that way. Intellisence only works with Control that are on the ASPX page itself. Not in another Control.